# How to make widget traffic exchanger script

Tags: widget, traffic

Does anyone know how to make a traffic widget exchanger script like those available on Wahoha.com and 2leep.com websites?..I have a website like them but I don't know how to make the traffic widget exchanger..

The script looks like this :

```
<!-- mysite.com Widget Traffic Exchanger : Start --><script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/widget/menegak/5.js"></script><!-- mysite.com Widget Traffic Exchanger : End -->
```

Comment: I have script for this. But it has some bug

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HitLeap](http://hitleap.com/by/rarauthor) to do that.

What is HitLeap?
HitLeap is a Traffic Exchange, also known as an autohits service
We help you increase your website hits, rankings (alexa, google) and more.
Our affiliate program gives cash and traffic commissions of up to 50%.
How does it work?
After signing up, you will submit all the websites you want to send traffic to.
Then you will earn free traffic by viewing other people's websites.
Alternatively, you could buy a traffic package from us.

[Sign up from this link](http://hitleap.com/by/rarauthor)